# fulltext index support in symfony 2.7.x or doctrine 2.5.x?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

I want to ask about fulltext index (for fulltext search) support in `doctrine 2.5.x` and `symfony 2.7.x.`

What I mean:

- Entitiy file --- `*@ORM\Index(name="column", columns={"column"}, **flags={"fulltext"}**)*`
- composer.json --- `*"doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5"*`

Will be this supported in `symfony 2.7.*` ? If not, which version will support it?

Comment: made an edit. Check if that's what you meant.

Comment: Yes, this I mean - if and when it will be supported

Comment: strange ... nobody knows ?

Comment: maybe you should ask developers on their website about upcoming features.